# how to generate columns with repeated values in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to get the following table using repeated data:

```html
   

 X1 X2  M1  Q   O
    1   1   m1  q1  20
    2   1   m2  q2  20
    3   1   m3  q3  16
    4   2   m1  q1  15
    5   2   m2  q2  12
    6   2   m3  q3  19
    7   3   m1  q1  17
    8   3   m2  q2  19
    9   3   m3  q3  17
    10  4   m1  q1  19
    11  4   m2  q2  15
    12  4   m3  q3  19
```

The column O is a random data between 12,20.

I have used the following codes, but it does not work

```html
tibble(x11 = c(1:12)) %>% 
  mutate(x2 = rep(row_number(), each=3, length.out = n()),
M1=rep(row_number("m"), each=3, length.out = n()),Q=rep(row_number("q"), each=3, length.out = n()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create the grouping by `rep`licating the `row_number()`, then create the 'M1', 'Q' by `paste`(`str_c`) ing the characters 'm', 'q' with the sequence of rows (`row_number()`) as well as use `sample` to sample numbers between 12 and 20 to create the 'O'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
tibble(X1= c(1:12)) %>% 
    group_by(X2 = factor(rep(row_number(), each=3, length.out = n()))) %>% 
    mutate(M1 = str_c('m', row_number()), Q = str_c('q', row_number()),
            O = sample(12:20, n(), replace = FALSE)) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 x 5
#      X1    X2 M1    Q         O
#   <int> <fct> <chr> <chr> <int>
# 1     1     1 m1    q1       17
# 2     2     1 m2    q2       19
# 3     3     1 m3    q3       20
# 4     4     2 m1    q1       15
# 5     5     2 m2    q2       13
# 6     6     2 m3    q3       17
# 7     7     3 m1    q1       14
# 8     8     3 m2    q2       17
# 9     9     3 m3    q3       15
#10    10     4 m1    q1       16
#11    11     4 m2    q2       19
#12    12     4 m3    q3       12
```

Comment: Many thanks, How I can make x2 as a factor?

Comment: @user330 just wrap `factor` around it

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe is df then:

```
df$O <- sample(12:20, nrow(df), replace = TRUE)
```